# systemctl status postgresql.service showing output as differently

Tags: postgresql, database-administration

1. Not coming out of os(Linux) prompt.Need to do ctrl+c to come out from prompt
2. output is not showing as expected(Active: activating (start) instead of Active: active (running))
   but postgresql services are starting.

```
# systemctl status postgresql.service
● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL database server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: activating (start) since Thu 2021-02-04 12:38:17 CET; 15min ago
     Docs: man:postgres(1)
 Main PID: 6688 (postgres)
   CGroup: /system.slice/postgresql.service
           ├─6688 /opt/data/pgsql/10.15/bin/postgres -D /opt/data/postgres/data/10/data
           ├─6689 postgres: logger process
           ├─6696 postgres: checkpointer process
```

```
cat /etc/systemd/system/postgresql.service

    [Unit]
    Description=PostgreSQL database server
    Documentation=man:postgres(1)
    
    [Service]
    Type=notify
    User=postgres
    ExecStart=/opt/data/pgsql/10.15/bin/postgres -D /opt/data/postgres/data/10/data
    ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
    KillMode=mixed
    KillSignal=SIGINT
    TimeoutSec=0
    
    [Install]
    WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

So please can any one help me to get desired output as Active: active (running))

Comment: I suspect it is because you have chosen `Type=notify` and the postgres binary doesn't send the notification. Do you have documentation suggesting that is the correct choice?

Comment: Yes,I followed the code in link    https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/server-start.html

Comment: When using systemd, you can use the following service unit file (e.g., at /etc/systemd/system/postgresql.service):
[Unit]
Description=PostgreSQL database server
Documentation=man:postgres(1)
[Service]
Type=notify
User=postgres
ExecStart=/usr/local/pgsql/bin/postgres -D /usr/local/pgsql/data
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
KillMode=mixed
KillSignal=SIGINT
TimeoutSec=0
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
Using Type=notify requires that the server binary was built with configure --with-systemd.

Comment: I am not configured with option configure --with-systemd while installing postgres

Comment: Which value i need to choose for Type parameter to get expected output.Please suggest.

Comment: If you didn't use that flag during build then I suspect you want "simple" or "forking" as described here https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html Are you sure it isn't packaged for your linux distribution though?

Comment: I am not sure on this.

Comment: With type=simple it is working...Thx Richard Huxton

Comment: good to hear you got it working.

Answer (score 0):

I tried comment the `Type=Notify` line and it works fine.
Only for PostgreSQL 9x.
Version 10 and above I've no problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).